# iOS In App Purchase Invalid Product Identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I developed an app with with an in app purchase, and was testing in sandbox mode with no problems. I submitted the app to the app store, which was just approved. The accompanying in app purchase was also approved.

However, the approved version can not access the in app purchase. Looking at the console, the in app purchase is returned in the invalidProductIdentifier list. However, it works fine on my simulator.

Not sure how to go about debugging this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other recommendations for Agreements/Taxing/Banking are good, I already had completed them.

In my case, it was simply a matter of the approved app binary propagating through the app store servers faster than my approved In-App-Purchase. After around 30 minutes, it began to work once the IAP was available on all of the servers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really post any comment, so I've been posting my comments as answers. I can only comment on my own answer. Anyway, this comment might be absurd or might be nonsense, but: I've read several articles before that sometimes IAP is not working on simulators.

I got two apps already on App Store that uses IAP, but never experienced that before. Try debugging using a real device.

Lastly, make sure that the **Agreements, Tax, and Banking** are all approved.